# How insert top n rows from excel or flat file to SQL destination using SSIS(version 2012)

Tags: t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a flat file and an excel file through which i have to insert only top 10 rows to SQL table. Is there is any property or settings that i may not know. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way and with out using script component is, using a 3rd party tool RowNumber Transformation from SQLIS. You can get it from here 
http://www.sqlis.com/post/Row-Number-Transformation.aspx

Use this transformation after your source. It will give you a new column with rownumber, then  use conditional split transformation to check rownumber <=10 and finally you can load the required output to your sql table using oledb or sql server destination.